# c# Equivalent to VB6 Public variable

Tags: c#, class, variables, module, public

Suppose I my project contains a Form and a Class. I would like to create a variable that can be accessed by both the Form *and* the class. In VB6 I could create a public variable in the (module / class), and easily access it like so:

**VB6 Example**

```
[Module code]

Public string_name as string

[/Module code]

[Form Code]

string_name = "test data"
MsgBox(string_name) ' Returns "test data"

[/Form Code]
```

How could I produce the above functionality with C#? I'm assuming I'd have to create a public class, but I'm not sure of the best way to declare public variables.

thank you,

Evan

Comment: You may want to consider using [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). It is not recommended practice to provide public access to members of your classes, e.g. they expose implementation detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same in c# (expose a field as public), though that is not good practice.

Use properties instead:

```
// public string property
public string string_name { get; set; }

// within class    
string_name = "test data";
MsgBox(string_name); 

// from another class
myClassInstance.string_name = "other test data";
```

Comment: Why is this not a good practice? This seems like it's just what I was looking for ...

Comment: @Evan - because this is exposing implementation details and is bad OOP (violates encapsulation and information hiding).

Comment: so you're saying it would be a lot smarter to just create and use the variables from the same form?

Comment: @Evan - My code example shows a property, not a field. I have shown _good_ practice.

Comment: Alright - I see your point. However, I guess I do not understand how a property is "safer" than a field. They seem to have the same functionality. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Evan - The _auto property_ I have shown allows you to change implementation at a later date without exposing internals. You can use a private field and add validation and more.

Comment: @Evan Oded implemented an autoproperty so the actual private field is hidden, generated by the compiler.  Autoproperties look almost the same as a simple public field.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `public static class` with a public static variable.

```
public static class MyPublicData
{

    public static string MyData1 = "My public data";

}
```

To use:

```
var x = MyPublicData.MyData1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int MyPublicVariable;
  public int MyPublicProperty {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Making the class and members static may be what you are looking for.

Comment: what effect does making the members / class static have?

Comment: @Evan: Making a member public and static means you can access it without creating an instance of the class. For instance, in this case, you can get/set the property using MyClass.MyPublicProperty.

Comment: And making a class static means you cannot create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a public class with a public static variable. Example:

```
public class PortalResources
    {
        #region Members

        public enum Mode 
        {
            LargeIconMode,
            SmallIconMode, 
            DetailsMode
        };

        public static int LargeIconSize = 150;
        public static int SmallIconSize = 75;
        public static string Name = "Name";

        #endregion

    }
```

Usage:

```
int IconSize = PortalResources.LargeIconSize;
int ViewMode = PortalResources.Mode.LargeIconMode;
```

Comment: could you please explain the purpose of the enum here?

Comment: I included it as an example because "public static enum" will not compile. You can use enum as a static without declaring it static. Of course, you don't have to use an enum unless your application calls for it. I put it in for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of a VB public (or global) variable is a public static property on a class.

You have to specify

```
Classname.PropertyName
```

To access it, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value to be a constant or static readonly value then place it in a static class:

```
public class Globals
{
    public const String value = "Hello World";
}

public static class Globals
{
    public static value2 = "Hello World";
}
```

If the value just needs to be accessible (not readonly), then you're better off sticking this value in a settings file and grabbing the setting.

Comment: you don't have to put const and readonly vars in a static class

Comment: you CAN put it in a static class, but you don't have to. in fact, I put them in the classes where they make sense... like MyPage.MaxLines for example